# How to know whether the tab bar is hidden in the controller pushed by a tabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, tabbar

I wanna observe the status of tab bar.I need to konw whether the tab bar is hidden in the controller pushed by a controller on TabBarController.The tab bar had been hidden when it's pushed by TabBarController.So how do I know whether the tab bar is hidden. 
By the way,I had tried to check the property "isHidden" in tab bar, but it didn't work.It always is NO.
Does anyone konw the method? Plz teach me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you tried to check the tabBar isHidden property on your tabBarController instance? something like self. tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden ?

Comment: Yes. I did it.But it didn't work. Its value is always NO.

Comment: @RanHassid it works after the view appeared.Do you have other methods to check when the controller initializes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we will need to use NotificationCenter as your status changes after the View-Life cycle methods are executed.

Write this code from where you are setting TabBar Hidden

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TabBarHiddenStatusChanged"), object: nil)
```

And this in viewDidLoad() of the ViewController Where you are checeking its status

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewControllerName.TabBarStatusCheck), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TabBarHiddenStatusChanged"), object: nil)
```

Add this Method

```
 func TabBarStatusCheck()  {
    if(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden
        == true){

    }
 }
```

Comment: it works after the view appeared.Do you have other methods to check it when the pushed controller initializes

Comment: Got it, I have edited code for you, hope it works. let me know

Comment: It works.But it is not I want. Actually, when I set the property that called `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` of the pushed controller, the property called `isHidden` of tab bar will be NO after pushed controller appeared. But it's still YES when the pushed controller is initializing even in `viewWillAppear` method.
I had other methods to fix my issues. Thx your help.

Comment: Before you push , you are hidding right ? use this code to hide self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden
        = true

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the tab bar from a controller by doing the following:

```
guard let parentTabController = tabBarController as?
MasterViewController else { return }

if parentTabController.tabBar.isHidden{
        //Logic if hidden
    }else{
        //Logic if not hidden
    }
```

MasterViewController is my class of the tab bar I am using.  Hopefully this helps you, I'm not sure how you were referencing your tab bar controller but this should work.

If you have a custom tab bar you can reference any of the custom properties this way.

Comment: it works after the view appeared.Do you have other methods to check when the controller initializes

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the following line of code to hide the tab bar for particular view controller:-

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

With this code you can hide the tab bar for particular view controller while pushing.

You can check the following condition in ViewWillAppear() or ViewDidLoad() method

if (self.tabBarController.hidden)
{
    NSLog("Tab Bar Controller Is Hidden");
}
else
{
   NSLog("Tab Bar Controller Is Not Hidden");
}
```

Comment: it works after the view appeared.Do you have other methods to check it when the pushed controller initializes